How to handle select event on Sankey Chart without rerender
Can someone help me how to handle select event on google react sankey chart?
I have parent component from where Im passing onSelect. With that I should update state (state is updated)
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts'

import css from '@/components/Charts/Sankey/sankey.module.scss'

const data = [
  ['From', 'To', 'Weight'],
  ['A', 'X', 5],
  ['A', 'Y', 7],
  ['A', 'Z', 6],
  ['B', 'X', 2],
  ['B', 'Y', 9],
  ['B', 'Z', 4],
]

const options = {
  sankey: {
    node: {
      label: {
        fontName: 'Times-Roman',
        fontSize: 12,
        color: '#000',
        bold: true,
        italic: false,
      },
      interactivity: true, // Allows you to select nodes.
      labelPadding: 6, // Horizontal distance between the label and the node.
      nodePadding: '10px', // Vertical distance between nodes.
      width: '10px', // Thickness of the node.
      colors: [
        '#a6cee3', // Custom color palette for sankey nodes.
        '#1f78b4', // Nodes will cycle through this palette
        '#b2df8a', // giving each node its own color.
        '#33a02c',
      ],
    },
  },
}

const SankeyChart = ({ onSelect }) => {
  return (
    <div className={css.sankeyChartContainer}>
      <Chart
        chartType="Sankey"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        data={data}
        options={options}
        chartEvents={[
          {
            eventName: 'select',
            callback: ({ chartWrapper }) => {
              const chart = chartWrapper.getChart()
              const selection = chart.getSelection()
              if (selection.length) {
                const selectedItem = selection[0]
                onSelect(selectedItem)
              }
            },
          },
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default SankeyChart

How to handle those rerender issues, where Im losing selected node style. I was trying to update state in my parent component, state is updated but chart component rerenders and selected node style is lost.
